# Register account 3 column page

Tags: customer-account, register

How can I set the register account page to a 3 column page?
I also want to display two (default) sidebars, left and right.

How can I achieve both?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jelle,you can do `this layout` and `set root template as 3columns`.

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

**Create local.xml at app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Template/layout/**

```
<?xml version="1.0.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account_create translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! But how do I display the sidebars?

Comment: If you column then it should be automatically call left &right section...May be bthe template is rewrited in other place ...